# Minimum value of $(x+1)^2+3$ with AM-GM

Tags: functions, inequality, quadratics, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Find the minimum value of $$(x+1)^2+3$$

I don't know how to use the AM-GM inequality.

I think in this case $a = (x+1)^2$ and $b = 3$. So, $$(x+1)^2+3 \geq 2\sqrt{3(x+1)^2}$$

And from here I don't know what I should do.

Comment: That's not the kind of minimum value problems that lends itself to AM-GM easily. The most common form is to have more variables (typically three), one constraint and one expression that is to be maximised or minimised under that constraint (optionally, show that some inequality holds). For a classic introductory example, given $x,y,z$ positive real numbers so that $xyz=1$, what's the minimum possible value of $x+y+z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted already (deleted since), the inequality does not lend itself to a natural proof by AM-GM.

For an overstrained proof, using just $\color{red}{\text{AM-GM}}$ and $\sqrt{x^2}=\color{blue}{|x| \ge -x}\,$:

$$(x+1)^2+3 = \color{red}{x^2+1} + 2x + 3 \ge \color{red}{2|x|} + 2x + 3 = 2(\color{blue}{|x|+x})+3 \ge \color{blue}{0} + 3 = 3$$

The lower bound of $3$ is attained for $x=-1\,$, so it is in fact a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Why you used A.M-G.M. inequality.
It can be done more easily.

Answer: We know that every square number is nonnegative. So $(x+1)^2\le 0$. Therefore, $(x+1)^2+3\le 3$.
Finally, the lower bound is 3 which attained when $(x+1)^2=0$, or, $x=-1$.

Comment: I guess you meant to write the two inequalities in the opposite direction. I.e.,
$(x+1)^2\ge 0$ and $(x+1)^2+3\ge 3$. (Rather than $(x+1)^2\le 0$ and $(x+1)^2+3\le 3$.)